# Creation of Merge Request in GitLab fails

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, merge-conflict-resolution

I migrated my existing sources from Microsoft SourceSafe to GitLab.

Now I have two branches `master` and `release`.

I created a third branch `feature` off `master` and committed and pushed this branch.

Afterwards, I created a new merge request, which got accepted and merged `feature` into `master` without conflicts. Now I want to cherry-pick this merge request into `release` which is 15 commits behind and 12 commits ahead to `master`.

When creating this merge request, I get an error saying "Sorry, we cannot cherry-pick this merge request automatically.

This merge request may already have been cherry-picked, or a more recent commit may have updated some of its content." and no merge request is created. This merge request isn't already cherry-picked as it is the first cherry pick ever in this repository and there also isn't a more recent commit that updated this file.

Additionally, GitLab won't show any entries related to my error in the internal log.

[image: merge request error message]

I want GitLab to create a merge request and let me resolve possible conflicts in the web interface. Is this possible?

Comment: `...let me resolve possible conflicts in the web interface.`: this is not possible AFAIK. We always resolve conflicts locally and push again.

Comment: this would be fine, but GitLab wont even create a merge request

Comment: also, according to http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/merge_requests/resolve_conflicts.html GitLab supports coflict resolution in the ui

Comment: You're right, it does. My information on this was outdated.

Comment: Can you cherry-pick locally on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in this case, create a new branch for your `release`, cherry pick to that branch, and then push that up as a separate merge request.

That's how we handle our release process when our `release` and `main` diverge from each other. It gets really obvious when I go on one of my refactoring sprees minutes after we branch off `release`. :D

Because of how Git works and the acyclic graph, you can't just reuse a commit, you basically have to manually create an identical one and push them up since the previous commits of `release` differ than `master`.